# IOS Local search for apps

Tags: ios, search

I have an app running on IOS (Iphone).
I want the users to be able to search for it on their local device search by two different languages.

How can i do this?
Currently it only finds the app if the user searches for it's name in the actual language the name is in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit/specifying_synonyms_for_your_app_name

Note the note about using localized app name by specifying variable names.